# to make a JSONP using jQuery, received a jXHR object with status of 200, but the fail() function was called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

using follow codes to make a JSONP request, the whole thing worked just fine, yet the .fail() was called, why?

```
function getJSONP(url, callback){
            var cbnum = "cb" + getJSONP.counter++,
                cbname = "getJSONP." + cbnum;
            getJSONP[cbnum] = callback;
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',        
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: "callback",
                jsonpCallback: cbname
            }).then(function (argument) {
                console.log("good");
            }, function (data, status, er) {
                console.log(status);
                console.log(data);
                console.log(er);
                console.log("error");
            })
        }
        getJSONP.counter = 0;
```

when i call getJSONP(), this function works fine, i get the data and the callback was also executed, but i get this too

```
parsererror
(index):478 Object {readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "success"}abort: (a)always: ()complete: ()done: ()error: ()fail: ()getAllResponseHeaders: ()getResponseHeader: (a)overrideMimeType: (a)pipe: ()progress: ()promise: (a)readyState: 4setRequestHeader: (a,b)state: ()status: 200statusCode: (a)statusText: "success"success: ()then: ()__proto__: Object
(index):479 Error: getJSONP.cb0 was not called(…)
(index):480 error
```

Hoping someone could tell me what's up? thanks!

Comment: how does your callback function look like?

Comment: `var cbnum = "cb" + getJSONP.counter++` here you are incrementing the value after concatenating the string .You have to increment before it is concatenated `var cbnum = "cb" + (1+getJSONP.counter)` try like this

Comment: @JohnAnkanna: What does it matter? Whether the callbacks are called `cb0`, `cb1`, etc or `cb1`, `cb2`, etc seems irrelevant.

Comment: @madalin ivascu here is my callback
`function parseData(data) {
            var datas = data.result.datalist;
            console.log(datas.length);
            var $titles = $(".game_list_item_text a");
            var $imgs = $(".vrwrap img");
            var $customers = $(".game_list_pingtai em");
            for (var i = 0; i < $imgs.length; i++) {
                $imgs[i].setAttribute("src", datas[i].picUrl);
                $titles[i].innerHTML = datas[i].gameName;
                $customers[i].innerHTML = datas[i].customer;
            }
        }`

Comment: @John Ankanna   i  dont think this would work

Answer (score 0):

From the log, it looks like the response could not be parsed (`parsererror`) and that the `jsonpCallback` was not called, see: `Error: getJSONP.cb0 was not called(…)`.

Comment: this is more like a comment then an answer

Comment: yes it does look like what you said, but i just wonder why?because everything works fine except the unexpected error handler was called?and i think cb0 was really called